# Firebase Client Side Data Fanout error on 2nd arguement

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase data fanout technique to update multiple locations. I have everything set up exactly like it should be as in the Firebase blog tutorial

the fanoutpost method takes three arguements

```
public Map fanoutPost(String uid, DataSnapshot followersSnaphot, Map post)
```

According to the tutorial, i am supposed to supply

mParents as gotten in

```
mParentsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mParents = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

as the second arguement

so that I can do this

```
mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Map message = new HashMap();
                message.put("broadcast",mMessage.getText());
                fanoutPost(mParentsRef.getKey(), mParents, message);
            }
        });
```

but i get the error that mParents is a map instead of the datasnapshot the arguement asked for.
This is actually very peculiar but it seemed to work in the tutorial and everybody went along with it, I am sure there must be something i am missing

[client side data fan out firebase blog tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)

Comment: Provide a link to the "Firebase blog tutorial".

Comment: Thanks, i just updated my question

Comment: Looks like a typo in the blog post. If you check the corresponding iOS example, you'll see that it passes the a follower **snapshot** as the second argument.

Comment: thanks Frank, i ll look into it.

Comment: Can i get the link to an updated tutorial